# Segmentation fault on JDownloader2 Install

Tags: pi-2

I'm trying to install JDownloader2 on my Pi and I'm following this [tutorial](https://steven-england.info/2014/11/23/setting-raspberry-pi-download-station-help-jdownloader2/).

But when I run:

```
java -jar /home/pi/jdownloader2/JDownloader.jar
```

I get:

```
Segmentation fault
```

what does this mean? And how can I fix this?

Comment: I think you might find a few suggestions from [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5404/segmentation-fault) useful. It's getting on a little, so I'm afraid I can't guarantee that everything in there will still work as intended.

Comment: @goobering What makes you think the error is related to `apt`?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an internal Java crash. You could try to install several JDK versions (right now there's `openjdk-8-jdk` to `openjdk-11-jdk`, plus you might have `oracle-javaX-jdk` pre-installed), and try them out one by one:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

If one of those works, you're in luck.

Answer (score 0):

A segmentation fault could imply the filesystem is corrupt.

If the error is only occurring when you are trying to install packages try running:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/*.bin
```

This might solve the problem but its certainly no guarantee. It might be necessary to backup anything important and have a go at reinstalling the OS on the SD card.

The error also could have been caused by you not fully expanding the filesystem to fill the size of the SD card. To check if this is the case or not run:

```
df -k
```

This will tell you if `rootfs` is completely filled or not.

If you do have to start afresh I suggest ensuring you are using a reputable SD card and a decent power supply, at least 5V 2A. Normally power or SD card issues are what lead to a filesystem becoming corrupted.

Comment: I've executed the command same problem

Comment: Ok, could you confirm for me that the `segmentation fault` error occurs when running other commands in the terminal, or is it just limited to installing packages?

Comment: when I install a package there is no error about segmentation fault, this error appear only if I try to execute this command `java -jar /home/pi/jdownloader2/JDownloader.jar`